# How can I initialize an empty Numpy array with a given number of dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I basically want to initialize an empty 6-tensor, like this:

```
a = np.array([[[[[[]]]]]])
```

Is there a better way than writing the brackets explicitly?

Comment: Also I am not entirely sure whether it is a good way of constructing such a tensor from the bottom up using `np.concatenate`.

Comment: What are you going to do with that empty array?

Comment: Iteratively adding rows of that rank-1 using `np.concatenate(a,b,axis=0)`.

Comment: It is a very, very bad idea: if you know the final size of your tensor allocate all of it with `np.empty` from the get go. If you need to build it "from the bottom up", you are very likely better off using nested Python lists, then calling `np.array` on the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) or [zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html).

For example, to create a new array of 2x3, filled with zeros, use: `numpy.zeros(shape=(2,3))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like `np.empty(shape = [1] * (dimensions - 1) + [0])`.
Example:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[[[[[]]]]]])
>>> b = np.empty(shape = [1] * 5 + [0])
>>> a.shape == b.shape
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use the [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor:

```
numpy.ndarray(shape=(1,) * 6)
```

Or the [`empty`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) variant, since it seems to be more popular:

```
numpy.empty(shape=(1,) * 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Iteratively adding rows of that rank-1 using np.concatenate(a,b,axis=0)

Don't.  Creating an array iteratively is slow, since it has to create a new array at each step.  Plus `a` and `b` have to match in all dimensions except the concatenation one.

```
np.concatenate((np.array([[[]]]),np.array([1,2,3])), axis=0)
```

will give you dimensions error.

The only thing you can concatenate to such an array is an array with size 0 dimenions

```
In [348]: np.concatenate((np.array([[]]),np.array([[]])),axis=0)
Out[348]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
In [349]: np.concatenate((np.array([[]]),np.array([[1,2]])),axis=0)
------
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
In [354]: np.array([[]])
Out[354]: array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=float64)
In [355]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,0)),np.zeros((3,0))),axis=0)
Out[355]: array([], shape=(4, 0), dtype=float64)
```

To work iteratively, start with a empty list, and `append` to it; then make the array at the end.

`a = np.zeros((1,1,1,1,1,0))` could be concatenated on the last axis with another `np.ones((1,1,1,1,1,n))` array.

```
In [363]: np.concatenate((a,np.array([[[[[[1,2,3]]]]]])),axis=-1)
Out[363]: array([[[[[[ 1.,  2.,  3.]]]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```py
x = np.array([])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).